# How to execute SALT.MODULES.WIN_LGPO MODULE

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am new to SALT and my requirement is to update set of policies programmatically to multiple systems.Then I came to know SALT can do perform my task.I went through documentation [salt.modules.win_lgpo](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_lgpo.html) . But I didn't understand how to execute it on my local machine ? Are there any prerequisites to execute win_lgpo module. I really appreciate any help or guidance

I have tried like this on my local system ,I have installed SALT on my system.I am getting following error.

```
C:\salt>salt '*' lgpo.get_policy_info 'Maximum password age' machine
Salt request timed out. The master is not responding. If this error persists after verifying the master is up, worker_threads may need to be increased
```

I want to get policy info like above and set policy like below

```
salt '*' lgpo.set computer_policy="{'LockoutDuration': 2, 'RestrictAnonymous': 'Enabled', 'AuditProcessTracking': 'Succes, Failure'}"
```

I am getting following error after some trial and error attempts from documentation

```
root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt-key -L
Accepted Keys:
Win2K_12_R2
Unaccepted Keys:
Rejected Keys:
root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt Win2K_12_R2 lgpo.get machine return_full_policy_names=True
Win2K_12_R2:
    'lgpo.get' is not available.
root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt Win2K_12_R2 test.ping
Win2K_12_R2:
    True
root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt Win2K_12_R2 secedit.set 'PasswordComplexity' 8
Win2K_12_R2:
    'secedit.set' is not available.
root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt Win2K_12_R2  secedit.configure section="System Access" setting="MinimumPasswordAge" value="10"
Win2K_12_R2:
    'secedit.configure' is not available.
root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt Win2K_12_R2 lgpo.get machine return_full_policy_names=True
Win2K_12_R2:
    'lgpo.get' is not available.
```

I got following error after executing in my minion windows machine . salt-call --local saltutil.sync_modules. One more question , is there anyway we can download modules and install on machine like pip ?

```
C:\salt>salt-call --local saltutil.sync_modules
[INFO    ] Loading fresh modules for state activity
[INFO    ] Creating module dir 'c:\\salt\\var\\cache\\salt\\minion\\extmods\\modules'
[INFO    ] Syncing modules for environment 'base'
[INFO    ] Loading cache from salt://_modules, for base)
[INFO    ] Caching directory '_modules/' for environment 'base'
local:
```

Comment: make sure `lgpo` module exists on your minion, you can try to `salt \* saltutil.sync_modules`, btw, this seems to be new in version `2016.11.0`, what's your ?

Comment: @Arount thanks for reply..I will check and get back to you

Comment: I have updated question with output that i got on my minion, can you please check and let me know what is the error .   root@hyi01lr0bsaehost92:~# salt Win2K_12_R2 lgpo.get machine return_full_policy_names=True
Win2K_12_R2:
    'lgpo.get' is not available.